# Pandas downsample timeseries from micro-seconds to minutes and process by each minute

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe contains stock price which freq is `micro-seconds`:

```
In [48]: fdf.iloc[:5]
Out[55]:
                                         #RIC    ...         Volume
Date-Time                                        ...
2019-03-05 09:30:06.283715885+08:00  .SSE100I    ...      8805000.0
2019-03-05 09:30:12.827067475+08:00  .SSE100I    ...      7843100.0
2019-03-05 09:30:18.388287730+08:00  .SSE100I    ...      7228800.0
2019-03-05 09:30:20.995625330+08:00  .SSE100I    ...      2471700.0
2019-03-05 09:30:25.450852863+08:00  .SSE100I    ...       929400.0

[5 rows x 7 columns]

In [56]: fdf.columns
Out[59]: Index(['#RIC', 'Domain', 'Date-Time', 'GMT Offset', 'Type', 'Price', 'Volume'], dtype='object')
```

I want to subset this dataframe by `minute` freq and calculate some statistics in each minute. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
def min_stats(df):
  import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(context=7)

fdf.resample('T').apply(df)
```

However, even though `fdf` has 7 columns, `df` in `min_stats` is a `pd.Series` which only contains the first column `#RIC`. How could I get all columns passed to `df`?

Comment: What is `print (fdf.dtypes)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html):

```
fdf.resample('T').agg(['min','max'])
```

Or [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), also is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html):

```
fdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='T')).agg(['min','max'])

fdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='T')).describe()
```

---

But all non numeric columns are exluded.

---

Your function should working like:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(context=7)

def min_stats(x):
    print (x)


fdf.resample('T').apply(min_stats)
```

Or:

```
def min_stats(x):
    print (x)


fdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='T')).apply(min_stats)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! `fdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='T')).apply(min_stats)` is exactly what I needed